# How to split column value using azure data factory

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

I have Source csv file, In which there is one column which have multiple values (data sep.by comma (,)) so I want extract that particular one column using data factory and store that multiple records into table (in database) with different column name

Could you please suggest how should I design that azure data factory pipeline ?

Comment: Are you saying the CSV file has individual columns with data separated by commas? That could be a whole problem in its own right. Nevertheless, Pipelines don't manipulate data directly, so you'll need to look at a Data Flow activity which will allow you to work with the data itself.

Comment: @Joel Cochran yes and particular column for eg , column name :custom which have mutiple comma sep data and that its data length is more than 2000 character , i want split the records who's length more than 2000 respectively .and (want give column name col1,col2,col3 and each column should contain 2000 chracter )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **split** function in the Data flow `Derived Column` transformation to split the column into multiple columns and load it to sink database as below.

**Source transformation:**

[image]

**Derived Column transformation:**

Using the [split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#split) function, splitting the column based on delimiter which returns an array.

[image]

**Derived Column data preview:**

Here 2 new columns are added in the derived column which stores the split data from the source column (name).

[image]

**Select transformation (optional):**

In Select transformation, we can remove columns which are not used in sink and only select required columns.

[image]

**Sink:**

Connect sink to the database and map the column to load the data.

[image]

Comment: Its userful  ! but i didnt understand how to save 2000 character in 1st derived column then another 2000 character in 2nd Derived column